A Spine for My Book with Pspicture
Consider the following code for a .767" spine with a height of 8.49".
\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn,openany,final]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,paperwidth=0.767in,paperheight=8.49in]{geometry}
%%%  Page size for 5.5" x 8.25" book spine of (.767in)---1.94818cm.

\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}

\usepackage{scalerel} % For Vertical Stretch of Letters
\usepackage{scalefnt}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{Gold}{RGB}{228,168,73}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cabin}


\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]% #1 = title
{\bgroup
  \huge
  \sbox0{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\textbf{\color{black}#1}}}%
  \sbox1{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\textbf{\color{Gold}#1}}}%
  \usebox0\llap{\raisebox{1.37pt}{\usebox1}}
\egroup}



\def\theLetterSpace{0.5pt}
\def\theWordSpace{1.5\LocalLetterSpace}
\newlength\LocalLetterSpace
\newcommand\spaceout[2][\theLetterSpace]{%
  \setlength\LocalLetterSpace{#1}\expandafter\spaceouthelpA#2 \relax\relax}
\def\spaceouthelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \spaceouthelpB#1\relax\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \kern\theWordSpace\spaceouthelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\def\spaceouthelpB#1#2\relax{%
  #1%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \kern\LocalLetterSpace\spaceouthelpB#2\relax%
  \fi
}



\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent\begin{pspicture}(-0.974,0)(0.974,21.555)%

\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{white}%
\psframe[fillcolor=black!96!green,fillstyle=solid](-0.974,0)(0.974,21.555)%
\psframe[linecolor=black!96!green](-0.974,0)(0.974,21.555)% draws frame.

\rput[tc]{-90}(0,15){\mytitle{\selectfont\scalefont{1.0}{\textbf{{\spaceout[4.0pt]{A SPINE FOR MY BOOK}}}}}}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}

It produces the output:

I am trying to rotate the title "A SPINE FOR MY BOOK" -90 degrees.
QUESTION: How may I get the title to appear (vertically, and) in its entirety on one line on the spine? I am compiling with Xelatex.
Thank you.
QUESTION:

it's not clear why you need pstricks here but if you want it on one line use \sbox0{\textbf{\color{black}#1}}% not \sbox0{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\textbf{\color{black}#1}}}%

You're right about pstricks; I neglected to take it out from the actual code when coming up with the MWE.

@DavidCarlisle And many thanks for the suggestion. It works fine on this end.

If you want text on one line you want an(\mbox rather than a \parbox, which allows line breaking. So use
\sbox0{\textbf{\color{black}#1}}%

not
\sbox0{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\textbf{\color{black}#1}}}%

